# When I refresh page, you can see a transition action?

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I have a little dilemma here. When I refresh the page in chrome I can see a transition action made by transition-duration on images and on the button on the bottom of the web page. The weird thing is that it does not happening on Firefox.On Mozilla it works without transition when you refresh the page. It works well only when you hover it. How can I fix it for chrome???

```css
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 border: 0;
 font-size: 100%;
 font: inherit;
 vertical-align: baseline;
}

/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
 display: block;
}
body {
 line-height: 1;
}

ol, ul {
 list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
 quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
 content: '';
 content: none;
}
table {
 border-collapse: collapse;
 border-spacing: 0;
}
/* Ending of resets */

.container
{
 width:1200px;
 height:1630px;
 background-color:grey;
 margin-left:auto;
 margin-right:auto;
 margin-bottom:10px;
}
.topmenu
{
 width:1200px;
 height:30px;
 background-color:skyblue;
 margin-left:auto;
 margin-right:auto;
}
.topmenu ul
{
 margin-left:100px;
}
.topmenu li
{
 float:left;
 margin-left:30px;
 margin-top:4px;
 font-size:17px;
 color:black;
}
.topmenu a
{
 color:black;
}
.logo2
{ 
 position:relative;
 font-size:35px;
 margin-top:20px;
 margin-left:150px;

}
.logo2 a
{
 text-decoration:none;
 color:black;
}
.content
{
 width:950px;
 height:350px;
 margin:30px auto;
}
.square1
{
 float:left;
 width:300px;
 height:300px;
 border-bottom:40px solid darkgrey;
}
.square1 img
{
 -webkit-filter:blur(5px);
 filter:blur(5px);
 transition-duration:1s;
 cursor:pointer;
}
.square1 img:hover
{
 -webkit-filter:blur(0);
 filter:blur(0);
}
.square2
{
 float:left;
 width:300px;
 height:300px;
 margin-left:25px;
 border-bottom:40px solid darkgrey;
}
.square2 img
{
 -webkit-filter:brightness(200%);
 filter:brightness(200%);
 transition-duration:1s;
 cursor:pointer;
}
.square2 img:hover
{
 -webkit-filter:brightness(100%);
 filter:brightness(100%);
}
.square3
{
 float:left;
 width:300px;
 height:300px;
 margin-left:25px;
 border-bottom:40px solid darkgrey;
}
.square3 img
{
 -webkit-filter:contrast(200%);
 filter:contrast(200%);
 transition-duration:1s;
 cursor:pointer;
}
.square3 img:hover
{
 -webkit-filter:contrast(100%);
 filter:contrast(100%);
}
.square4
{
 float:left;
 width:300px;
 height:300px;
 border-bottom:40px solid darkgrey;
}
.square4 img
{
 -webkit-filter:drop-shadow(8px 8px 10px orange);
 filter:drop-shadow(8px 8px 10px orange);
 transition-duration:1s;
 cursor:pointer;
}
.square4 img:hover
{
 -webkit-filter:drop-shadow(12px 12px 14px green);
 filter:drop-shadow(12px 12px 14px green);
}
.square5
{
 float:left;
 width:300px;
 height:300px;
 margin-left:25px;
 border-bottom:40px solid darkgrey;
}
.square5 img
{
 -webkit-filter:grayscale(100%);
 filter:grayscale(100%);
 transition-duration:1s;
 cursor:pointer;
}
.square5 img:hover
{
 -webkit-filter:grayscale(0);
 filter:grayscale(0);
}
.square6
{
 float:left;
 width:300px;
 height:300px;
 margin-left:25px;
 border-bottom:40px solid darkgrey;
}
.square6 img
{
 -webkit-filter:hue-rotate(90deg);
 filter:hue-rotate(90deg);
 transition-duration:1s;
 cursor:pointer;
}
.square6 img:hover
{
 -webkit-filter:hue-rotate(360deg);
 filter:hue-rotate(360deg);
}
.square7
{
 float:left;
 width:300px;
 height:300px;
 border-bottom:40px solid darkgrey;
}
.square7 img
{
 -webkit-filter:invert(100%);
 filter:invert(100%);
 transition-duration:1s;
 cursor:pointer;
}
.square7 img:hover
{
 -webkit-filter:invert(0);
 filter:invert(0);
}
.square8
{
 float:left;
 width:300px;
 height:300px;
 margin-left:25px;
 border-bottom:40px solid darkgrey;
}
.square8 img
{
 -webkit-filter:saturate(8);
 filter:saturate(8);
 transition-duration:1s;
 cursor:pointer;
}
.square8 img:hover
{
 -webkit-filter:saturate(2);
 filter:saturate(2);
}
.square9
{
 float:left;
 width:300px;
 height:300px;
 margin-left:25px;
 border-bottom:40px solid darkgrey;
}
.square9 img
{
 -webkit-filter:sepia(100%);
 filter:sepia(100%);
 transition-duration:1s;
 cursor:pointer;
}
.square9 img:hover
{
 -webkit-filter:sepia(0);
 filter:sepia(0);
}
.square10
{
 float:left;
 width:300px;
 height:300px;
 border-bottom:40px solid darkgrey;
}
.square10 img
{
 -webkit-filter:opacity(30%);
 filter:opacity(30%);
 transition-duration:1s;
 cursor:pointer;
}
.square10 img:hover
{
 -webkit-filter:opacity(100%);
 filter:opacity(100%);
}
.square11
{
 float:left;
 width:300px;
 height:300px;
 margin-left:25px;
 border-bottom:40px solid darkgrey;
}
.square11 img
{
 -webkit-filter:contrast(150%) brightness(200%);
 filter:contrast(150%) brightness(200%);
 transition-duration:1s;
 cursor:pointer;
}
.square11 img:hover
{
 -webkit-filter:contrast(100%) brightness(100%);
 filter:contrast(100%) brightness(100%);
}
.square12
{
 float:left;
 width:300px;
 height:300px;
 margin-left:25px;
 border-bottom:40px solid darkgrey;
}

.loadmore
{
 position:relative;
 margin:50px auto;
 width:100px;
 height:100px;
 border-radius:30px;
 background-color:orange;
 text-align:center;
 transition-duration:1s;
}
.loadmore:hover
{
 background-color:skyblue;
}
.loadmore a
{
 color:black;
 text-decoration:none;
}
.loadmore h1
{
 padding-top:37px;
 font-size:20px;
 font-weight:bold;
}
.footermenu
{
 width:600px;
 height:30px;
 background-color:yellow;
 margin:10px auto;
}

.footermenu li
{
 width:150px;
 height:30px;
 float:left;
 text-align:center;
 margin-top:5px;
 font-size:18px;
}
.footermenu a
{
 color:black;
 text-decoration:none;
}
form
{
 float:right;
 margin-right:140px;
 margin-top:-25px;
 z-index:999;
}
 label
 {
  z-index:999;
 }
input
{
 width:150px;
 z-index:999;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Just Web</title>
 <meta name="description" content="" />
 <meta name="keywords" content="" />
 <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; scale=1" />
 <link href="tristastyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
 <link rel="icon" href="images/favicon.ico">
</head>

<body>
 
<div class="container">
  
 <div class="header">
 
  <div class="topmenu">
   <nav>
   <ul>
    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Project</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">menu</a></li>
   </ul> 
   </nav>
  </div>
  
  <div class="logo2"><a href="index.html">protosite</a></div>
  
  <form>
    <label for="fname">search</label>
    <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname">
  </form>
  
 </div>
 
  <div class="content">
    <div class="square1"><img src="images/girls/image1.png"></div>
    <div class="square2"><img src="images/girls/image2.png"></div>
    <div class="square3"><img src="images/girls/image3.png"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="square4"><img src="images/girls/image4.png"></div>
    <div class="square5"><img src="images/girls/image5.png"></div>
    <div class="square6"><img src="images/girls/image6.png"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="square7"><img src="images/girls/image7.png"></div>
    <div class="square8"><img src="images/girls/image8.png"></div>
    <div class="square9"><img src="images/girls/image9.png"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="square10"><img src="images/girls/image1.png"></div>
    <div class="square11"><img src="images/girls/image2.png"></div>
    <div class="square12"><img src="images/girls/image3.png"></div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="loadmore">
   <a href="#"><h1>Load more</h1></a>
  </div>
  
  <div class="footermenu">
   <nav class="navig">
   <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Policy</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">FAQ</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
   </ul> 
   </nav>
 </div>
  
</div> 
  
 
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this to your classes:
-moz-filter:opacity (as much as you want)

If this makes the Firefox transition like chrome, and you don't want that, then remove the -webkit-filter:

Comment: without webkit it transition doesn't work on chrome.